# Passing C array as char* function parameter

Tags: c, arrays

I've got some code I'm mantaining with the following variable declaration:

```
char tmpry[40];
```

It's being used with this function:

```
char *SomeFunction(char *tmpryP) {
   // Do stuff.
}
```

The function call is:

```
SomeFunction(&tmpry[0]);
```

I'm pretty damn sure that's just the same as:

```
SomeFunction(tmpry);
```

I've even checked that the char* pointer in SomeFunction ends up pointing to the same memory location as the array in both cases.

My question is a sanity check as to whether the two function calls are identical (and therefore the original programmer was just being nasty)?

Comment: I think it would be good to pass a length also to SomeFunction, just in case... :)

Comment: The name of the character array is an alias for the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: Hello, I'm one of those "nasty" programmers who writes like this. Generally, I do this in C++ code, for the reason of lesser coupling to the array abstraction used at the moment. I.e. for an *abstract* array-like data structure (like `std::vector<char>`) with overloaded `operator []` expressions `x` and `&x[0]` will get to mean very different things, and the *second* one is the one which fits better for my intent. Off course, all this doesn't matter so much for plain C, since you get almost none data abstraction in C anyway; thus the spelling with superior readability should be preferred.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

they are exactly the same.

```
someArray[i]
```

means exactly

```
*(someArray + i)
```

where someArray in the second case is a pointer to the memory location. Similarly,

```
&someArray[i]
```

means exactly

```
(someArray + i)
```

In both these cases the terms are pointers to memory locations.

Answer (score 12):

The two are equivalent and I think SomeFunction(tmpry); is more readable.

Answer (score 7):

It *may* be significant, if `SomeFunction` is a macro and takes `"sizeof"` of one of its arguments, because `sizeof(tmpry)` may not necessarily be equal to `sizeof(&tmpry[0])`.

Otherwise, as others pointed out, they are exactly the same.

Comment: In this case there is no macro involved. However how would a macro treat them differently? Doesn't a macro work like a string search and replace so the function it produced would be equivalent to a normal function anyway?

Comment: Results will differ if the macro takes sizeof(macro argument).

Comment: #define Macro(x) RealFunctionCall(x,sizeof(x)) // For example

Answer (score 5):

The [C Programming FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) section on [arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) tackles this (and many other common C questions and confusions.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone else said, the two notations are equivalent.

I would normally use the simpler one, unless there are multiple calls like this:

```
SomeFunction(&tmparry[0]);
SomeFunction(&tmparry[10]);
SomeFunction(&tmparry[NNN]);
```

Where ideally all the constants (magic numbers) would be enum (or `#define`) constants.

Comment: well, even then, tmparry + 10 is better than &tmparray[10]

Comment: I disagree - but it is a subjective decision.

Answer (score 1):

Both are one and the same although second one looks nice and clarifies the intention of passing the array to the function. But how does the SomeFunction know the size of the array being passed, is it always assumed as 40 ? I feel it is better to pass the size also as the parameter to SomeFunction.

Comment: I agree, you should pass the size as well as the array.

Comment: I agree if it is a new code, but if the code is already written it may not be possible to change the datastructures so easily..

Comment: Also, we have no idea if C++ is an option since the question said C array and the tag is simply C

Answer (score 1):

These two variants are equivalent and passing like this

```
SomeFunction(tmpry);
```

looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

int a[10];
int *pa;

There is one difference between an array and a pointer that must be kept in mind. 
A pointer is a variable, so pa=a and pa++ are legal.
But an array name is not a variable; construction like a=pa and a++ are illegal

As format parameters in a function definition,
char s[]
and 
char *s 
are equivalent;

From: [The C Programming Language 2th](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628), Page 99-100

Comment: To quote from page 99: "When an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the location of the initial element"